# Execute plsql dynamiclly via SSH in remote server (using dynamic login info) and get returned value to executing server

Tags: oracle, shell, dynamic, return-value

I am trying to execute a dynamic plsql command in a remove machine (say 192.168.x.x) and get it's return value to local machine from where I initiate shell script. I am testing two approaches to do this. But none of them seems to work properly.

Approach - I
in this approach if i supply values for ssh and sqlplus (login user/ip and schema user/ip) via shell variable it won't work. working code with hardcoded value is below.

```
#!/bin/sh
varfld="SYSDATE"
retVal=`echo "SELECT $varfld FROM dual;" | ssh utility@192.168.x.x 'sqlplus -S utility/pwd' | tail -2 | head -1`
echo "return value 1: "$retVal
```

Approach - II
In this approach I can pass everything i need in a variable. But the plsql command (i.e value of variable $ssh_execute_command) is not recognized inside plsql. Only hardcoded plsql command gets executed.

P.S.This works fine with vsql with few modification to connect Vertica.

```
v_server_user=utility
v_server_name=192.168.x.x
ssh_v_schema_name=utility 
ssh_v_schema_pwd=pwd

varfld="SYSDATE"
execute_command="SELECT $varfld FROM dual;"
retVal=$(ssh $v_server_user@$v_server_name ssh_v_schema_name=$v_schema_name ssh_v_schema_pwd=$v_schema_pwd ssh_execute_command=\""$execute_command"\" 'bash -s' <<SSHSQLTEXT
sqlplus -S $ssh_v_schema_name/$ssh_v_schema_pwd
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;
SSHSQLTEXT
)
echo "return value 2: "$retVal
```

Queries
1. How can we make sql command passed in a variable make work inside pqlplus? or
 
2. How can we pass required values for ssh and sqlplus (login user/ip and schema user/ip) dynamically and make it work?

The sql statement "SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;" used here is for testing purpose only. I will be calling package function instead to get return value. And this is yet to be tried in any of these scenarios. If anyone could address that too with example, that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of sqlplus to a variable which must be displayed within ssh so that the result is passed to variable retVal. Try the following code:

```
retVal=$(ssh $v_server_user@$v_server_name ssh_v_schema_name=$v_schema_name   ssh_v_schema_pwd=$v_schema_pwd ssh_execute_command=\""$execute_command"\" 'bash -s' <<SSHSQLTEXT
sqlresult=`sqlplus -S $ssh_v_schema_name/$ssh_v_schema_pwd <<EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;
exit
EOF`
echo $sqlresult
SSHSQLTEXT
)
echo "return value 2: "$retVal
```

If you execute the above block of codes, you will have the sysdate as result in $retval